# Access $scope.variable from $scope.function

Tags: angularjs

In this code my `console.log` logs `undefined`. I am trying to access $scope property from other $scope method. How to do this properly?

```
AppControllers.controller('DepartureLocationCtrl', [
  '$scope','$http',
  function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/airports').success(function(data){
      $scope.departureLocations = data;
    });
    $scope.showSuggestions = function(){
      console.log($scope.departureLocations);
    }
    $scope.showSuggestions()
}]);
```

Comment: show suggestions is sync, while airports http callback is async. Other than that there's not problem accessing scope variables from functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code tries to log the value of `$scope.departureLocations` immediately after you have **sent** the http request to get them from the backend. At this time, the http response has not come back yet, and the `$scope.departureLocations = data;` line has not been executed yet.

The first A in AJAX means *Asynchronous*.

Move `$scope.showSuggestions()` inside the function passed to `success()`. And BTW, use then() instead of `success()`: `success()` is deprecated.

```
AppControllers.controller('DepartureLocationCtrl', [
  '$scope','$http',
  function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/airports').then(function(response){
      $scope.departureLocations = response.data;
      $scope.showSuggestions()
    });

    $scope.showSuggestions = function(){
      console.log($scope.departureLocations);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Oh, seriously, I made same mistake with async and sync thing again. I think, this time it's a last time, lesion learned.